# add class to the specified element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok, i have this code

```
//start our session
session_start();
//check if there is a page request
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
//if there is a request page then get it and put it on a session variable and sent back the data that was requested.
$_SESSION['page'] = $_GET['page'];
$currentpage = $_SESSION['page'];
}
//if there is no request then..
else
{
$_SESSION['page'] = "home"; //if there is no request page then we literally tell that we are in the main page so we session will be home
$currentpage = $_SESSION['page'];
}

//echo a hidden input fields that hold the value of current page which will be accessed  by the jquery for adding classes of the match value in the attribute 'page' of the element base on the value that the hidden input field has

echo "<input type='hidden' id='currentpage' value='".$currentpage."' />
```

now, i want to add a class 'active' to the element that match the value of the attribute 'page' into the value of the hidden input field which has the id of 'currentpage', in order to do that, i prefer to make it on jquery so heres the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//get the value of the hidden input field
$page = $('#currentpage').val();
//now im stuck here ..
});
```

I dont know how to add a class on the specified element that has a match value of its attribute 'page' from the value of the hidden field which has an id of 'currentpage'

for example:

```
<input type='hidden' id='currentpage' value='home' />
```

so base on the attr 'page' of the element an active class should be added, so this should be like this.

```
<ul>
    <li><a page="home" href="index.php" class="active">home</a></li> <!--as you can see on this part an active class has been added thats because the value of the attr page of this element is match to the value of the hidden input fields which has the id of 'currentpage'-->
    <li><a page="gallery" href="index.php?page=gallery">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a page="about" href="index.php?page=about">about</a></li>
    <li><a page="contact" href="index.php?page=contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope someone could give me something that could help to solve this current issue, thanks in advance.

PS: im open in ideas, suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: Have you come across the jQuery function called `.addClass()` yet?

Comment: Read the jQuery Documentation before asking anything

Comment: Unless you're sending over this data via ajax, why not have PHP output the class for you?

Comment: (Note that Javascript variable names *can* start with a `$`, but, unlike PHP, they don't have to. Just a heads-up in case future developers will be working with this, since prefixing all variables with `$` is a rare style in the Javascript world.)

Comment: on a side note, validate `$_GET['page']` against your list of pages, just for good measure, if later on you decide to pass that variable to a DB for example

Comment: @Pointy: I know how to add class but how to add class as match to the value of the hidden input fields which has an id of 'currentpage'

Comment: @AlvinWong: excuse me, what are you pointing out? i read that jquery documentation, as we know in that case, it only give basic.. now i know how to add class in jquery, but how to add class as match to the value of the hidden input fields which has an id of 'currentpage'

Comment: @MarcB: right, but the menu which use for jquery to be hook in was from database also.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Tell me that you have read [this page in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
$("a[page="+$page+"]").addClass("active");
```

Comment: This will work fine after the declaration of your page variable, which should be defined as so: `var $page = $('#currentpage').val();`

Answer (score 5):

```
 $('a[page='+$page+']').addClass('active');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/6mHKg/)