# JQuery add to <class>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add class to the specified element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597489/add-class-to-the-specified-element)

Let's say I load up a website that has this in its code:

```
<span id="test">
```

Lets say I want to create a jQuery script that finds that specific line of code and adds `class="voila"`, so the outcome becomes:

```
<span id="test" class="voila">
```

Comment: You can learn about these basic things by having a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/. If you haven't done so yet, you should read the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: Let's say you do some basic research next time, huh?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test").addClass('voila');
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
$('span#test').addClass('voila');
```

`$('span#test')` this part finds that line of code and addClass('voila') add the class voila to the span.

Comment: `$('span#test')` this part finds that line of code and `addClass('voila')` add the class `voila` to the `span`.

Comment: You can just [**edit your answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14617585/edit) instead of commenting on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class to the respective span using JQuery

```
 $("#test").addClass('voila');
```

`$("#test")` finds the matching element from the `DOM` and `addClass()` method adds the required class to the matched element or the set of matched elements.

If you have another class `"bingo"`, and you want to add both classes to the span then add classes separated by spaces and you are done.

```
$("#test").addClass("voila bingo");
```

Answer (score 0):

add class

```
$('#test').addClass('voila');
```

remove class

```
$('#test').removeClass('voila');
```

and toggle class

```
$('#test').toggleClass('voila');
```